# Can I use single Google API credential for multiple deployed microservices for same user on different instances?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-workspace

Application1 -> Microservice1 (deployed on one server, also db is separate)

Application2 -> Microservice2 (deployed on other server, also db is separate)

**NOTE** : For Microservice1 and Microservice2 we are use same Google API credentials.

We have a one application in that we are providing user to edit it's word, ppt, excel files with Online editor.

So, we have configure Microservice which used GSuite API for user to edit there file with google online word editor.

Now, we have a scenario like when one user open file from Application1 then our application will redirect user to google login screen and once user enter it's credentials then google will check whether third-party application already registered with login user account or not, and if not then google will give consent screen to register third-party app with current user.

Once user allow third-party app then google will redirect user to our Microservice1
once callback came to our Microservice then we will store user's refresh-token to our db and user can able to edit document online.

Now, user open file from Application2 and it will redirect user to google login screen and once user enter it's same credentials which he used in above then google will check whether third-party application already registered with login user account or not, this time google found that third-party application already registered with them, and google will redirect user to Microservice2, but this time google doesn't give refresh-token and in our db also refresh-token entry not there, so we will not able to open the file in online editor.

So, is there any way to handle these kind of scenario with only single Google API Credential?

Or we need separate account which give us different Google API Credentials?

Like :

Microservice1 (One Google Account with Google API Credential)

Microservice2 (Another Google Account with Google API Credential)

Any kind of help appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

you need to [create a service account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en), possibly with [G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation).

Comment: Thanks @Martin, but there is a problem with service account base approach,
like when any user open the file then it will store that file into the drive of service account user. we have a security concern related to files so we only need to store that file into logged in user's google drive.

Comment: is there any other way to do this?